# How to upload images on selected folder in Cloudinary using PHP Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary

I created Cloudinary account and made a "posts" folder.

I want to store all images upload on posts folder but I don't know how to do that.

I'm using this package https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel yeah, Its working fine but its uploaded in '/'directory. When I'm passing ['folder' => 'posts/'] as second argument, it get an error signature.

Comment: You're typing &#39; instead of ' for some reason

Comment: In order to add a folder, you can add the folder name to your public_id. For example, "folder" => 'posts' and then add it to your $filename when upload.

Comment: @ShirlyManor can you give me an example please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("myImage.jpg", 
  array("folder" => "my_folder/my_sub_folder/", "public_id" => "my_image", "overwrite" => TRUE, 
"resource_type" => "image"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's say the name of the folder is posts

```
$image_path = $request->file('image_name')->getRealPath();

Cloudder::upload($image_path, null, array("folder" => "posts", "overwrite" => TRUE, "resource_type" => "image"));
```

the null parameter allows cloudinary to generate a unique public id for the uploaded image.

> public_id: "posts/unique_id.png",